How do I create and/or initialize an attribute in Python?
Attempting to make a calculator in Python, and an error shows up twice saying that 'Calculator" has no attribute 'key', as well as an issue with something else. How to I fix these errors?
I attempted to initialize the attribute as best I could, and another error occurred. The errors are on lines 31 and 59
Edit: We good. If you want to try this, Git repo is https://github.com/DerpOKat21/Random-projects
import tkinter as tk

class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Calculator")

        # Create display
        self.display = tk.Entry(master, width=35, borderwidth=5, font=('Arial', 16))
        self.display.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10)

        # Create buttons
        button_list = [
            '7', '8', '9', '/',
            '4', '5', '6', '*',
            '1', '2', '3', '-',
            '0', '.', '=', '*'
        ]

        row = 1
        col = 0
        for button_text in button_list:
            button = tk.Button(master, text=button_text, width=5, height=2, font=('Arial', 14),
            command=lambda x=button_text: self.button_click(x))
            button.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=5, pady=5)
            if col == 3:
                col = 0
                row += 1
            else:
                col += 1
            # Bind keyboard keys
            self.master.bind('<Key>', self.key_press)

    def button_click(self, button):
        current = self.display.get()
        if button == 'C':
            self.display.delete(0, tk.END)
        elif button == '=':
            try:
                result = eval(current)
                self.display.delete(0, tk.END)
                self.display.insert(0, str(result))
            except SyntaxError:
                self.display.delete(0, tk.END)
                self.display.insert(0, "Error")
        else:
            self.display.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.display.insert(0, current + button)

    def key_press(self, event):
        key = event.char
        if key in '0123456789+-*/.':
            self.button_click(key)
        elif key == '\r':
            self.button_click('=')
        elif key == '\x1b': # Escape key
            self.display.delete(0, tk.END)

root = tk.Tk()
calculator = Calculator(root)
root.mainloop()


Unident def button_click and def key_press so they're in the class, not within each other, then you seem to have a typo on self.key.press

Now it's telling me that there's a syntax error at self.master.bind('' self key.press) and it thinks that it's missing a comma. How do I fix that?

Not sure why the comma was removed. There's still no self.key. The function is called self.key_press with an underscore

Ohh. I fixed that, and now the only issue is that comma.

Which comma? self.master.bind('<Key>', self.key_press). There's two parameters here, so the comma is needed

I put it back, and it brought back the issue from earlier.

You'll have to be more specific, please if you fixed the underscore, you should no longer have "has no attribute 'key'" message. Did you unident the button and key functions? You can [edit] your question to show your changes and the complete error log when running the code

Yes, I unidented those. Its missing 'key_press'

Your code still shows button_click within init function, and key_press within that. All functions should be at the same indentation under the class to have the same self reference

I'm not exactly sure what that means. Is there a way you could dumb it down, or perhaps I could send you a link to a GitHub repo and see if you could put an example of how I should fix it.

If I take your code and fix the indentation so all of the defs line up, it works just fine.  https://gist.github.com/timrprobocom/e742f5ece1b3acd4d64245ffbf3127df

I have another issue. It's doubling inputs and there's only one button. What about that?

You have both  multiply Button widget. One of them could be Clear button.

What is "we good" supposed to mean?

"We good" refers to that the issue was fixed.

Besides of your code indetention for the functions, your math is and flow cotrol are also of,
as you never change the col number you will stay put at the first button and pile them up, one after another
import tkinter as tk

class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Calculator")

        # Create display
        self.display = tk.Entry(master, width=35, borderwidth=5, font=('Arial', 16))
        self.display.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10)

        # Create buttons
        button_list = [
            '7', '8', '9', '/',
            '4', '5', '6', '*',
            '1', '2', '3', '-',
            '0', '.', '=', '*'
        ]

        row = 1
        col = 0
        for button_text in button_list:
            button = tk.Button(master, text=button_text, width=5, height=2, font=('Arial', 14),
            command=lambda x=button_text: self.button_click(x))
            button.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=5, pady=5)
            if col == 3:
                col = 0
                row += 1
            else:
                col += 1
            # Bind keyboard keys
            self.master.bind('<Key>', self.key_press)

    def button_click(self, button):
        current = self.display.get()
        if button == 'C':
            self.display.delete(0, tk.END)
        elif button == '=':
            try:
                result = eval(current)
                self.display.delete(0, tk.END)
                self.display.insert(0, str(result))
            except SyntaxError:
                self.display.delete(0, tk.END)
                self.display.insert(0, "Error")
        else:
            self.display.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.display.insert(0, current + button)

    def key_press(self, event):
        key = event.char
        if key in '0123456789+-*/.':
            self.button_click(key)
        elif key == '\r':
            self.button_click('=')
        elif key == '\x1b': # Escape key
            self.display.delete(0, tk.END)

root = tk.Tk()
calculator = Calculator(root)
root.mainloop()


you do understand that you shpuld not correct the question, when someone answers, you accept the answer and go on with life see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

command is never used anywhere. Is it needed?

@OneCricketeer he is startin with python and had problems, i think the command will be inserted at a later stage

@nbk I have never used Stack Overflow, I'm not familiar with how to accept an answer. Thank you for at least reminding me what to do next time.
